# Setting autoresizesOutlineColumn on NSOutlineView has no effect

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

The Cocoa documentation states:

```
setAutoresizesOutlineColumn:
Sets whether the receiver automatically resizes its outline column when the user expands or collapses an item.

- (void)setAutoresizesOutlineColumn:(BOOL)resize
Parameters
resize
    YES if the outline column is automatically resized, otherwise NO.
Discussion
    The outline column contains the cells with the expansion symbols and is generally the first column. The default is YES.
```

However no matter what I set this value to when expanding my NSOutlineView's items the 1st column does not expand.

I set the value in IB via the "Autoresizes Outline Column" option and the Outline Column is set to Column 0.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 on MacOS 10.8.4.

The NSOutlineView is a View based NSOutlineView.

Comment: Same here, did you solve this problem?